# How to return the response of a post request in qraphql

Tags: javascript, node.js, graphql

I'm developing an app using GraphQL in the backend and I want to implement a face comparison method. I am using the [facepp npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/facepp-rest-api), which gives me an API to perform the comparison. The problem I am having is that when my resolver runs, it finishes before it gets a response from facepp. How can I make it return the response from facepp?

```
    module.exports = {
      Mutation: {
         checkFace: async () => {
           console.log("Checking.....");

        let confidence;

        var parameters = {
          image_url1: "link to image 1",

          image_url2: "link to image 2",
        };

        facepp.post("/compare", parameters, function (err, res) {
            if (!err) {
                confidence = res.confidence;
              //return res.confidence doesn't work
            } else {
                confidence = "There was an error"
            }
        });

        return confidence
    },
},
```

};

Comment: don't duplicate ... use await !!

Comment: can you please clarify me more? what is the work around please?

Answer (score 1):

After a couple of trials and researches, I came up with a working solution. The problem in my original code was that I didn't correctly handle the asynchronous handler of the `facepp.post` method. In case if someone runs into the same issue, below is a working implementation of my code.

```js
module.exports = {
    Mutation: {
        checkFace: async () => {
            let confidence;
            const callCheck = () => {
                return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                    var parameters = {
                        image_url1: "link to image 1",
                        image_url2: "link to image 2",
                    };
                    facepp.post("/compare", parameters, function (err, 
                  res) {
                        if (!err) {
                            confidence = res.confidence;
                            resolve();
                        } else {
                            confidence = "error";
                            reject();
                        }
                    });
                });
            };
            await callCheck();
            return confidence;
        },
    },
};
```